# Remove duplicate entries from a CSV file

Tags: text-processing, files

I've got a [csv] file with duplicate datum reprinted ie the same data printed twice. I've tried using [sort's uniq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq)
by `sort myfile.csv | uniq -u` however there is no change in the `myfile.csv`, also I've tried `sudo sort myfile.csv | uniq -u` but no difference.

So currently my csv file looks like this

```
a
a
a
b
b
c
c
c
c
c
```

I would like to look like it

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: sort -u myfile.csv > tmp.csv ; mv -f tmp.csv myfile.csv

Comment: according to `man sort`, you can't sort "in place".

Comment: You can also try to not rely on the terminal. You can try this online tool instead
http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/basic-text-tools/remove-duplicate-lines/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The reason the `myfile.csv` is not changing is because the `-u` option for `uniq` will *only* print unique lines. In this file, all lines are duplicates so they will *not* be printed out.

However, more importantly, the output will not be saved in `myfile.csv` because `uniq` will just print it out to `stdout` (by default, your console).

You would need to do something like this:

`$ sort -u myfile.csv -o myfile.csv`

The options mean:

- `-u` - keep only unique lines
- `-o` - output to this file instead of `stdout`

You should view `man sort` for more information.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to maintain order of the file (not sorted) but still remove duplicates you can also do this

```
awk '!v[$1]++' /tmp/file
```

For example

```
d
d
a
a
b
b
c
c
c
c
c
```

It will output

```
d
a
b
c
```

Comment: Could you please expand on the syntax?

Comment: Place the string in a hash. If the string does NOT exist in the hash then print.

Comment: As far as I see, this is the best answer. How it works:

1. Awk starts and creates an empty array v.
2. Awk reads each line from the file /tmp/file.
3. For each line Awk extracts the first field ($1) (or $0 to full line).
4. Awk checks if this field has already been seen by looking in the array v.
5. New Value: If the field hasn't been seen before (!v[$1] is true) it stores a value of $1 in the array v for that field (v[$1]++) and prints the line.
7. Duplicate Value: If the field has already been seen (!v[$1] is false) it doesn't print the line and increments the counter.

Answer (score 3):

As Belmin showed, sort is great.  His answer is best for unsorted data, and it's easy to remember and use.

However, it is also volatile, as it changes the order of the input.  If you absolutely need to have the data go through in the same order but removing later duplicates, awk may be better.

```
$ cat myfile.csv
c
a
c
b
b
a
c


$ awk '{if (!($0 in x)) {print $0; x[$0]=1} }' myfile.csv
c
a
b
```

Weird edge case, but it does come up from time to time.

Also, if your data is already sorted when you are poking at it, you can just run uniq.

```
$ cat myfile.csv 
a
a
a
b
b
c
c
c
c
c


$ uniq myfile.csv 
a
b
c
```

Drawback to both of my suggestions is that you need to use a temporary file and copy that back in.

Answer (score 2):

[uniq](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html) `-u` only print unique lines. Your input has no unique lines, so `uniq -u` print nothing. You only need `sort`:

```
sort -u myfile.csv
```