# Removing Duplicates from a CSV based on specified columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I am working with a CSV data set which looks like the below:

```
year,manufacturer,brand,series,variation,card_number,card_title,sport,team
2015,Leaf,Trinity,Printing Plates,Magenta,TS-JH2,John Amoth,Soccer,
2015,Leaf,Trinity,Printing Plates,Magenta,TS-JH2,John Amoth,Soccer,
2015,Leaf,Trinity,Printing Plates,Magenta,TS-JH2,John Amoth,,
2015,Leaf,Metal Draft,Touchdown Kings,Die-Cut Autographs Blue Prismatic,TDK-DF1,Darren Smith,Football,
2015,Leaf,Metal Draft,Touchdown Kings,Die-Cut Autographs Blue Prismatic,TDK- DF1,Darren Smith,Football,
2015,Leaf,Trinity,Patch Autograph,Bronze,PA-DJ2,Duke Johnson,Football,
2015,Leaf,Army All-American Bowl,5-Star Future Autographs,,FSF-RG1,Rasheem Green,Soccer,
```

It contains a number of duplicates that I need to remove (keeping one instance of the record).  Based on [Remove duplicate entries from a CSV file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189684/remove-duplicate-entries-from-a-csv-file/189725#189725) I have used `sort -u file.csv --o deduped-file.csv` which works well for examples like

```
2015,Leaf,Trinity,Printing Plates,Magenta,TS-JH2,John Amoth,Soccer,
2015,Leaf,Trinity,Printing Plates,Magenta,TS-JH2,John Amoth,Soccer,
```

but does not capture examples like

```
2015,Leaf,Trinity,Printing Plates,Magenta,TS-JH2,John Amoth,Soccer,
2015,Leaf,Trinity,Printing Plates,Magenta,TS-JH2,John Amoth,,
```

Where the data is incomplete, but is a representation of the same thing.

Is it possible to remove duplicates based on specified fields e.g year, manufacturer, brand, series, variation?

Comment: Does your CSV file actually have those line breaks in it? The ones for "Darren Smith"'s entries?  If not, then don't post it like that - it's a red herring distracting potential answerers.   If it does, then it's broken - CSV requires multi-line fields to be quoted.

Comment: BTW, your requirements are moving towards the edge of what's possible with simple line-oriented tools.  You probably need to use a tool like GNU [datamash](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/), Miller aka [mlr](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), or [csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit).  Or use a language with CSV libraries like perl ([Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/release/Text-CSV) module) or python ([csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library).

Comment: @cas thanks for the comment.  I've corrected the CSV structure in the question, the line breaks are not present in the data.  Thanks for the links - I'll take a look

Comment: If your data is "simple" CSV (i.e. no quoted delimiters within fields, like `"John Amoth, Jr"`, at least not up to and including the fields that you wish to use as the deduplication key) then you can likely use something as simple as `awk -F, '!seen[$1, $2, $3, $4, $5]++' file.csv`. See [How does awk '!a\[$0\]++' work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a "key" of the first 5 fields, and then only print a line if that key is being seen for the first time:

```bsh
awk -F, '
  {key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5}
  !seen[key]++ 
' file
```

```
year,manufacturer,brand,series,variation,card_number,card_title,sport,team
2015,Leaf,Trinity,Printing Plates,Magenta,TS-JH2,John Amoth,Soccer,
2015,Leaf,Metal Draft,Touchdown Kings,Die-Cut Autographs Blue Prismatic,TDK-DF1,Darren Smith,Football,
2015,Leaf,Trinity,Patch Autograph,Bronze,PA-DJ2,Duke Johnson,Football,
2015,Leaf,Army All-American Bowl,5-Star Future Autographs,,FSF-RG1,Rasheem Green,Soccer,
```

Comment: That's great, works perfectly.  For my own knowledge, if I wanted to match on the third and fifth fields would I just modify e.g. `{key = FS $3 FS $5}`?

Comment: Yes. You could omit the leading FS

Answer (score 3):

Decorating first with awk to retain your header line at the top during the sort then using any awk+sort+cut:

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '{print (NR>1), $0}' file | sort -u -t, -k1,6 | cut -d, -f2-
year,manufacturer,brand,series,variation,card_number,card_title,sport,team
2015,Leaf,Army All-American Bowl,5-Star Future Autographs,,FSF-RG1,Rasheem Green,Soccer,
2015,Leaf,Metal Draft,Touchdown Kings,Die-Cut Autographs Blue Prismatic,TDK-DF1,Darren Smith,Football,
2015,Leaf,Trinity,Patch Autograph,Bronze,PA-DJ2,Duke Johnson,Football,
2015,Leaf,Trinity,Printing Plates,Magenta,TS-JH2,John Amoth,Soccer,
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-`awk` solution: one may simple use `sort`, define fields 1 to 5 as comparision `-k`eys, use `,` as field separator (`-t`) and select `-u`nique entries only:

```
 sort -t, -k1,5 -u infile
```

However this will make the header line last. Use either `-r` for reversed sorting or separate the header line via e.g.

```
{ sed 1q infile ; sed 1d infile | sort -k1,5 -t, -u ; }
```